# How to create record in database for each month by participants in django

Tags: python, sql, django, database

I am working on an app where a user can create a committee and the participants will pay the amount each month like this.I am quite new with coding and databases so i am little confused.

```
class committee(models.Mode):
   name= ...
   per_amount=...
   and some other columns will go here...
class participants(models.Model):
   parti_name= ..
   parti_committee_name = models.foreignkey(Committee)
   some other columns here
```

Now what I want is I want the records of each participant for each  month, they can only pay once a month and then they are allow to pay next month. now I am confused where to put the month column, is there going to be a new column for this or not?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please write the first letter of the classes in a capital letter.
2. Add new column: `next_payment = models.DateField()`
3. Within a `@classmethod`, write an if condition to check if the next payment due.
4. Use [Celery](https://pypi.org/project/celery/) to schedule the function.